# Need to populate a textfield with email ids based on the checkbox checked for different towers

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have 4 towers and I need checkboxes for each of them. Based on checking any combnation of them the 'txtNotifTo' textbox should get populated with the respective group of email ids for each tower selected.

Please help me find out what is going wrong in this code.

When the checkbox is checked, I get this error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
> 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference*

```
function getChNotifValue() {
       
  var listItems = document.getElementById("txtTowerValue").getElementsByTagName("input");
  var cb1 = listItems[0];
  var cb2 = listItems[1];
  var cb3 = listItems[2];
  var cb4 = listItems[3];
  var cb5 = listItems[4];                        

  var emailaddress = document.getElementById('<%=txtNotifTo.ClientID%>');
  // var email = [];
                  
  var emailList = [];

  if (cb1.checked) {
    emailList.push("Admin@test.com");
  } else {
    emailList = removeEmail(emailList, "Admin@test.com");
  }
  if (cb2.checked) {
    emailList.push("Admin1@test.com");
  } else {
    emailList = removeEmail(emailList, "Admin1@test.com");
  }
  if (cb3.checked) {
    emailList.push("Admin2@test.com");
  } else {
    emailList = removeEmail(emailList, "Admin2@test.com");
  }
  if (cb4.checked) {
    emailList.push("Admin3@test.com");
  } else {
    emailList = removeEmail(emailList, "Admin3@test.com");
  }
  if (cb5.checked) {
    emailList.push("Admin4@test.com");
  } else {
    emailList = removeEmail(emailList, "Admin4@test.com");
  }

  emailaddress.value = emailList.join(', '); // Concatenate the email address to NotifTo variable
}
```

**THE HTML CODE:**

```
<tr>
  <td class="toconditions" style="border-color: lightblue">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label21" Font-Bold="true" Text="To" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="700px" SkinID="EmailTextbox" ID="txtNotifTo" />
  </td>
</tr>

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="txtTowerValue" runat="server" SkinID="EmailTextbox" Font-Size="14px" Width="580px" Height="30px" BorderStyle="None" onClick="getChNotifValue()" >  
  <asp:ListItem Text="I1" Value="ch1" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="I2" Value="ch2" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="I3" Value="ch3" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="I4" Value="ch4" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="I5" Value="ch5" />                               
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

> I altered the code in the Javascript function and added the below code instead as txtNotifTo is a ASP.NET server control.

`var listItems = document.getElementById('<%=txtNotifTo.ClientID%>').getElementsByTagName("input");`

When I ran the code after this I am getting this error.

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'checked' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Post your HTML code. So far it seems element with ID `txtTowerValue` is missing.

Comment: @JanPfeifer - added the HTML code

Comment: the error itself clearly refers to this line: `document.getElementById("txtTowerValue").getElementsByTagName("input");` meaning that there's no element with id `txtTowerValue`. As far as I remember about asp.net, those asp.net web controls (`<asp:CheckBoxList ...`) are expected to have an attribute like `clientID` to specify the id the html embedded element should have (instead of `ID` being the server side id of the control). But it's been long time I don't deal with .net

Comment: What is probably Diego D trying to say you need to change `id` to `clientId` or just add `clientId`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientid?view=netframework-4.8#system-web-ui-control-clientid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using a jQuery selector would be easier.

but, your code will look like this:

```
                ckList = document.getElementById('<%= txtTowerValue.ClientID %>')
                ckBoxInList = ckList.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")

                if (ckBoxInList[0].checked) {
                    alert("Check box " + ckBoxInList[0].value + " is checked")
                }

                if (ckBoxInList[1].checked) {
                    alert("Check box " + ckBoxInList[1].value + " is checked")
                }
```

Comment: Thanks Albert , I tweaked the solution above to work for my code. I was using the variables before to check if else condition which was not working but now I am using the indexed variable 'chBoxInList' and I am able to populate the textbox.